# Fat arrow functions in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I understand that left side of `=>` is about passing parameters and right side of `=>` is the body of the function.

So, I understand the following:

```
let x = ( a: number, b: number) => { console.log("") }
```

Please explain the following:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

```
let myAdd: (x: number, y: number) => number =
    function(x: number, y: number): number { return x + y; };
```

What are they doing here? What's the use of this?

Comment: It's adding all the types to everything explicitly. So, the type of `myAdd`, the type of `x`, the type of `y`, and the return type of the function.

Comment: @VLAZ Is this an anonymous function?

Comment: You'll have to define what you mean by "anonymous function". A somewhat recent question here shook my confidence in that term. What I personally understand it as, then yes - it's anonymous function. Reason is that there is really nothing at all special to anonymous functions. Literally the only thing they are defined as is not having a name. Which is a shifting definition with newer standards. However, I *assume* you mean "function expression" because they are a subset of anonymous functions but are actually worth thinking and talking about. So, if that's what you mean - then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let myAdd: (x: number, y: number) => number = function(x: number, y: number): number { return x + y; };
           ^------------------------------^   ^------------------------------------------------------^
                   type definition                        the value (which is function)
```

`myAdd` is typed as a function that takes two numbers and returns a number. The function that is assigned to `myAdd` is of that type (takes two numbers, return one), so typescript is happy.

It may have confused you that the function type definition uses the `=>` symbol also, but this is not the javascript arrow function here. That is typescript syntax.

Comment: Is this an anonymous function?